# When using ssr: false (aka SPA-only), what are the benefits of Nuxt over Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

In `nuxt.config.js` I have configured `ssr: false` and I'm using some static hosting.
I understand that Nuxtjs with `ssr: false` is CSR (Client Side Rendering).

I wonder what is the difference between Nuxt and Vue in that case?

Answer (score 4):

Nuxt's purpose is mainly SSG/SSR/Edge rendering (or anything tied to have your code coming from a server step at some point).

If you use `ssr: false`, you will indeed lose a lot of Nuxt's strengths, meanwhile, you will still have:

- simple route creation with file-based rather than configuring a `router.js` file
- automatic code-splitting of your routes
- the whole Nuxt modules ecosystem
- middlewares on the client side
- auto-imported components and Vue's `ref`, `reactive`, `onMounted` etc for you (if using Composition API)
- cool data fetching capabilities (if using Composition API)
- automatic TS configuration (if using Nuxt3)
- [more benefits...]

---

As you can see, even if you use Nuxt as SPA-only, you will still get some quality of life improvements in your developer journey (better "DX").
Is it worth an abstraction on top of vanilla Vue? Maybe, depends on how fast/custom you want your code to be and if you don't feel like re-implementing the features already available in Nuxt.