# does using nuxt with `ssr: false` makes nuxt same as regular vue with nodejs hosting?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

if you set `ssr: false` in `nuxt.config.js` file, does this make nuxt work exactly same as plain Vue application?

if so, doing `npm run build`, `npm run start` will just serve static html/css/js file with node.js server?

Am I right here?

Comment: In my experience, setting that option to false does absolutely nothing. I'm using Nuxt 3.0.0.

Comment: @paddotk you're missing an important part here so. Getting your content rendered on the server is quite a big deal tbh.

Comment: @kissu I'm not sure what that has to do with how/whether that option works?

Comment: @paddotk of course setting `ssr` to either `true` or `false` will impact the rendering and the way Nuxt works. So yeah, it does quite a lot. SPA-only VS SSR/SSG + hydration is quite not the same.

Comment: @kissu I understand what it's supposed to do, but doesn't work. At least not in v3.0.

Comment: @paddotk I just tried it by creating a brand new Nuxt3 app. Works flawlessly and as intended regarding the rendering. You should have some other issues or maybe an auth module running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that will make Nuxt behave like Vue for the rendering part.
Be sure to have `generate` for an SSG target and not `build` (for SSR).

Here are more details of the benefits of still using Nuxt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74714106/8816585

---

If you're doing `npm run build`, it's supposing that you're using your Nuxt app as SSR. Which means pretty much nothing since you don't want SSR (`false`).

It's like saying

> I want a tomato sandwich, but without the tomato.

In the current situation, Nuxt3 will probably give you a sandwich but without tomatoes aka `SPA-only` Nuxt3 generated as SSG. Totally hostable as any other regular SPA app, on Netlify.

Official source: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#client-side-only-rendering

---

Also, what Nuxt is doing during local development and on production are 2 different things.
You will always have a Node.js server running for dev, but that is not the case once deployed (SSG, SPA, etc...).
If you want a Nuxt3 SSR'ed app, use `build` + `ssr: true`.

Comment: So, `build` + `ssr: false` would work like plain vue app? although it would mean giving up the main benefit of using nuxt.

Comment: `build` + `ssr: false` means pretty much nothing (tomato example). `generate` + `ssr: false` is behaving like a regular Vue app yes. Would be quite unoptimized to HAVE to run a Node.js server just to display an SPA. So no `build` in that case, it's only used for SSR (`generate` is for SSG which an SPA is totally fine with since you can drop it on a CDN like Netlify's platform). @Guest-01

Comment: so, `build` will include node server which in this case seems unnecessary. `generate` will output `dist` which can be seen in vue project. I think I got the idea. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Guest-01 pretty much yes!

Answer (score 1):

From the nuxt3 [document](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#route-rules)

> ssr - Disables server-side rendering for sections of your app and make them SPA-only with ssr: false

What I understand from the doc

**When SSR is false and use `npm run build`**

If you make `ssr: false` and build the project not generate, then It will work like a simple vue spa application. Like a traditional spa application, it will load the whole js in the initial load and then render in the client site.

**When SSR is false and use `npm run generate`**

Again if you make `ssr: false` and generate the project not build, Then it will prerender all the pages and generate the static file. And it will work like a traditional static website. *But you have to be careful that as SSR is false it will not prefetch any data it needs in the generated time. So It's best to generate pages with SSR mode on.*